# Unity3d Calculate Microphone input into dB (sound level meter) / creating a reverberation calculator

Tags: database, volume, microphone

I´ve got a specific question about the microphone input. When i use the microphone (for example headset or an integrated microphone on a mobile device) it doesnt recognizes sounds or noise signals very good - or on high distances (like 1-2 meters).

Is there a possibility like a microphone.gain setting or something, i could increase the range of recognized sounds? A sensivity or something. I would need a "maximum" on sensivity to recognize volume changes in the room.

Can someone help me out with this?

Thank you very much!